# Angular2 dropdown select element with multiple group options do not show current value

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular2 app has dropdown element with 3 option groups, it looks like this:

```
<select formControlName="reasonCode" id="reasonCode" class="form-control">
      <option value="" [ngValue]="null"></option>
      <option *ngFor="let reason of otherLeavingReasons" [ngValue]="reason.longName">
        {{reason.longValue}}
      </option>
      <optgroup label="Managed">
        <option *ngFor="let reason of managedLeavingReasons" [ngValue]="reason.longName">
          {{reason.longValue}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Unmanaged">
        <option *ngFor="let reason of unmanagedLeavingReasons" [ngValue]="reason.longName">
          {{reason.longValue}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

I added this piece to each of option group to position element on current value:

```
[selected]="reason.longValue == eventForm.controls['reasonCode'].value.longValue"
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I suspect it is because of presence of 3 option groups. 
Is there any other way to do that or perhaps different component capable of holding such groups in single option group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted that finally by trail and error method. It loooks like [ngValue] and [selected] cannot be used together,or at least in my app. Selection started to work when I removed [ngValue].
It doesn't mean it the final and recommended solution but it work in this case. So the final working code look like this:

```
<select formControlName="reasonCode" id="reasonCode" class="form-control" (change)="markTouched('reasonCode')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let reason of otherLeavingReasons" [selected]="reason.longValue == eventForm.controls['reasonCode'].value">
        {{reason.longValue}}
      </option>
      <optgroup label="Managed">
        <option *ngFor="let reason of managedLeavingReasons" [selected]="reason.longValue == eventForm.controls['reasonCode'].value">
          {{reason.longValue}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Unmanaged">
        <option *ngFor="let reason of unmanagedLeavingReasons" [selected]="reason.longValue == eventForm.controls['reasonCode'].value">
          {{reason.longValue}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `ReactiveModule` forms. In this form you don't need to set `[selected]` in every `option`. Even you never need to set `[selected]` attribute to add for set as selected. Just set model value and you will angular will update your UI.

In your code put this code in `component`

```
this.form.controls['reasonCode'].patchValue("myvalue");
```

Comment: Well, I thought the same but somehow select element doesn't wok. It is absolutely fine when I change it for regular input but not a dropdown. This is actually the only form element causing issues so I thought there is some kind of better replacement.

Comment: Can you provide us plunker link for your problem so we can update on plunker for better solution

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, this is part of my work. I can only update my question here. As I said this is some kind of generic issue with dropdown element in  angular2 as this problem exist on every page containing select element. Another idea I have is to use hidden input element as the form control and then sync it with select element but I don't how to do this either.